# Cannot Submit All Data in Form React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a very basic form in React, and I am having difficulty getting the data to submit properly.  In this current setup, only the 'content' field is submitting correctly, eventhough the firstName, lastName, and email are all written the same.  The radio buttons and dropdown are also not submitting.  Any ideas?

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import '../ticket.min.css'
class Ticket extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            email: '',
            content: ''
        }
        this.ticketName = React.createRef();
        this.state = { tickets: [] };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onValueChange = this.onValueChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        alert('Your ticket has been submitted');
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    onValueChange = event => {
        this.setState({
            selectedOption: event.target.value
        });
    }

    addTicket = () => {
        let url = "http://localhost:8080/tickets";
        axios.post(url, { firstName: this.ticketName.current.value, lastName: this.ticketName.current.value, email: this.ticketName.current.value, content: this.ticketName.current.value }).then(response => {
            this.ticketName.current.value = "";
            alert('Your ticket has been submitted');
        });
    };

    getData = () => {
        let url = "http://localhost:8080/tickets";

        axios.get(url).then(response => this.setState({ tickets: response.data }));
    };


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <label>First Name:</label>
                    <input ref={this.ticketName} type="text" name="firstName"/><br></br>
                    <label>Last Name:</label>
                    <input ref={this.ticketName} type="text" name="lastName"/><br></br>
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    <input ref={this.ticketName} type="text" name="email"/><br></br>
                </form>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>
                        Select a Category:<br></br>
                        <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                            <option value="hardware">Hardware</option>
                            <option value="software">Software</option>
                            <option value="internet">Internet</option>
                            <option value="other">Other</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                </form>
                <form>
                    <label>Please Describe Your Issue:</label><br></br>
                    <textarea name="content" ref={this.ticketName}/>
                </form>

                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

                    <label>
                        Select the Urgency Level:<br></br>
                        <input type="radio" value="Urgent" checked={this.state.selectedOption === "Urgent"} onChange={this.onValueChange} />Urgent<br></br>
                        <input type="radio" value="Normal" checked={this.state.selectedOption === "Normal"} onChange={this.onValueChange} />Normal<br></br>
                        <input type="radio" value="Low Priority" checked={this.state.selectedOption === "Low Priority"} onChange={this.onValueChange} />Low Priority
                    </label>
                </form>

                <form>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.addTicket}>Submit</button>
                </form>

                <h3>Pending Tickets</h3>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.getData}>Show Pending</button>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.tickets.map(p => (
                        <li key={p.id}>

                            {p.firstName}{p.lastName}
                            {/* {p.firstName} : { p.complete ? "complete" : "not complete" } <button type="button" className="btn btn-success">Complete</button><button type="button" className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button> */}
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Ticket;
```

Answer (score -1):

You should put fields in one form element and set the button type to submit.